# ASP.NET MVC - HTML Error "No ViewData of Type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

It's just a simple application that allows me to add music to a database via a HTML form.

What is happening is when I try to submit the data to be committed into the DB, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type
> 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Genre'.

This error is appearing on the HTML page and from my assumptions, is passing a NULL value instead of the what I have chosen.

Music service class:

```
    public void AddMusic(MusicGenreArtist musicGenreArtist, string userID)
    {
        Music newMusic = new Music()
        {
            Title = musicGenreArtist.Title,
            num_track = musicGenreArtist.num_track,
            duration = musicGenreArtist.duration,
            DateReleased = musicGenreArtist.DateReleased,
            Price = musicGenreArtist.Price,
            Image = musicGenreArtist.Image
        };

        using (var context = new ForestContext())
        {
            musicDAO.AddMusic(newMusic, context);
            Genre genre = genreDAO.GetGenre(musicGenreArtist.Genre, context);
            genreDAO.AddMusicToCollection(newMusic, genre, context);

            Artist artist = artistDAO.GetArtist(musicGenreArtist.Artist, context);

            artistDAO.AddMusicToCollection(newMusic, artist, context);
            userDAO.AddMusicToCollection(newMusic, userID, context);
        }
    }
```

Genre DAO:

```
    public Genre GetGenre(Music music, ForestContext context)
    {
        IList<Genre> genres = GetGenres(context);
        for (int i = 0; i < genres.Count; i++)
        {
            if (genres[i].Musics.Contains<Music>(music))
            {
                return genres[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

DAO for music:

```
    public void AddMusic(Music music, ForestContext context)
    {
        context.Musics.Add(music);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Music Controller:

```
    public ActionResult AddMusic()
    {
        Helper helper = new Helper();
        ViewBag.genreList = helper.GetGenreDropDown();
        ViewBag.artistList = helper.GetArtistDropDown();
        return View();
    }

    // POST: AddMusic/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddMusic(MusicGenreArtist musicGenreArtist)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            musicService.AddMusic(musicGenreArtist, "user");
            return RedirectToAction("GetGenre", "Genre", 
                    new { id = musicGenreArtist.Genre });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Helper controller for dropdown:

```
public class Helper
{
    private IGenreService genreService;
    private IArtistService artistService;
    public Helper()
    {
        genreService = new GenreService();
        artistService = new ArtistService();
        
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> GetGenreDropDown()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> genreList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        IList<Genre> genres = genreService.GetGenres();
        foreach (var item in genres)
        {
            genreList.Add
                (
                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = item.Name,
                    Value = item.ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = (item.Name == (genres[0].Name) ? true : false)
                }
                );
                
        }
        return genreList;
    }
    public List<SelectListItem> GetArtistDropDown()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> artistList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        IList<Artist> artists = artistService.GetArtists();
        foreach (var item in artists)
        {
            artistList.Add
                (
                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = item.Name,
                    Value = item.ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = (item.Name == (artists[0].Name) ? true : false)
                }
                );

        }
        return artistList;
    }



}
}
```

Genre Model:

```
 public class Genre
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Music> Musics { get; set; }
   
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" 
})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genre, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.genreList)               
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you add your update method that you use in your controller ?

Comment: @B.S. I assume your talking about my add music, I have updated the post for you now

Answer (score 0):

The model you are sending in your view and the one you are waiting for in your controller doesn't match.

Your view use the model `Genre`

But your controller :

```
public ActionResult AddMusic(MusicGenreArtist musicGenreArtist)
```

is waiting for `MusicGenreArtist`

Please double check this

Comment: I missed out a crucial piece of code which I think is the issue (GenreDAO), please have a look when you can. My MusicService pulls out the ID of the Genre and then sets the field in MusicGenreArtist to that ID. Thats why I would assume the controller expects MusicArtistGenre. So do you think I need to change this from Genre genre = genreDAO.GetGenre(musicGenreArtist.Genre, context); to Genre genre = genreDAO.GetGenre(Genre.ID, context);?